# Envío de Datos en trama GPS sin GPRS

Tags: geolocalización, gps, localización

Trabajado con dispositivos GPS (control de flotas), uno de los mayores inconvenientes a la hora de disponer de una localización en tiempo real es de la necesidad de disponer de una conexión de Datos en todo momento. En el caso de perdida de datos o conexión a internet, la única alternativa que conozco hasta el momento es la modalidad de GPS offline en la que la información de localización se almacena en el dispositivo local hasta que la conexión se restablece y los datos almacenados son volcados al servidor.

Últimamente me han llegado rumores de la posibilidad de utilizar el propio paquete de intercambio con el satélite para el envío de una cantidad limitada de datos, sin necesidad del uso de una conexión a internet. Alguien sabe si esto es parte de la "rumorología popular" o hay algo de cierto en ello? ¿ En caso afirmativo, conoceis algo de documentación ? ¿ Si envío datos en la trama GPS, como puedo acceder a ella posteriormente ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Ivan, bienvenido. Si te pasas por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) verás que las preguntas aquí no tratan rumores ni opinion personal ni busqueda de documentacion. Has de investigar e intentar implementarlo. Si te surjen errores de codigo, o problemas al programar, entonces preguntar aqui. Un saludo

Comment: Entendido, gracias.